# Huge space on Post Widget elementor Pro. Please see picture

Tags: post, widget, space, elementor

As you can see on the picture, there is a huge space between the elements of blog. The picture, title, body, read more are far from each other.

[image]

Comment: Did you use something like (Min-)Height for the section?

Comment: yes I did. Still no effect.

Comment: You should remove the (Min-)Height.